# Implement Send Email Functionality using Dependency Service

Tags: email, xamarin, dependency-injection, xamarin.forms

Implement **Send Email Functionality using Dependency Service**.Following fields should be configurable **To,Cc,Bcc,Subject and Details**.

I tried many examples such as [example1](http://%20https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/62243/how-to-send-smtp-email-using-xamarin-forms-without-user-interaction) and [Example2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41063172/send-email-from-xamarin-forms-app-using-dependency-service) and many more. None of that helped.

I'm able to do it in the code behind using Xam.Plugins.Messaging but I need to implement the email service using Dependency service. And I have no clue how to fix this. Any suggestions?

Comment: Why can you not stick with the Messaging plugin?

Comment: the first link has to do with sending e-mail via SMTP, bypassing the platform native UI.  That seems to be very different than what you're asking.  It would also help if you explained what specifically you're having problems with.

Comment: @Tom I can't stick with Messaging plugin because I want to use dependency injection. Because we can't add cc and attachments also lots of email functionality needs dependency injection.

Comment: @Jason I want a sample working code where the sending email is implemented using dependency injection. And I'm not finding any example related to it.

Comment: the plugin does support cc and attachments: https://github.com/cjlotz/Xamarin.Plugins/blob/master/Messaging/Details.md#attachments

Comment: @Jason how can I add Cc can u provide me an example?

Answer (score 0):

the API docs include an example of using [cc](https://github.com/cjlotz/Xamarin.Plugins/blob/master/Messaging/Details.md#using-the-api)

```
// Alternatively use EmailBuilder fluent interface to construct more complex e-mail   with multiple recipients, bcc, attachments etc.
var email = new EmailMessageBuilder()
  .To("to.plugins@xamarin.com")
  .Cc("cc.plugins@xamarin.com")
  .Bcc(new[] { "bcc1.plugins@xamarin.com", "bcc2.plugins@xamarin.com" })
  .Subject("Xamarin Messaging Plugin")
  .Body("Well hello there from Xam.Messaging.Plugin")
  .Build();

emailMessenger.SendEmail(email);
```

and [Attachments](https://github.com/cjlotz/Xamarin.Plugins/blob/master/Messaging/Details.md#attachments)

```
var email = new EmailMessageBuilder()
  .To("to.plugins@xamarin.com")
  .Subject("Xamarin Messaging Plugin")
  .Body("Well hello there from Xam.Messaging.Plugin")
  .WithAttachment("<path_to_picture>", "image/jpeg");
  .Build();
```